# Sort files in directory then execute command on each one of them

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing files numbered like this

```
1>chr1:2111-1111_mask.txt
1>chr1:2111-1111_mask2.txt
1>chr1:2111-1111_mask3.txt
2>chr2:345-678_mask.txt
2>chr2:345-678_mask2.txt
2>chr2:345-678_mask3.txt
100>chr19:444-555_mask.txt
100>chr19:444-555_mask2.txt
100>chr19:444-555_mask3.txt
```

each file contains a name like `>chr1:2111-1111` in the first line and a series of characters in the second line.
I need to sort files in this directory numerically using the number before the `>` as guide, the execute the command for each one of the files with `_mask3` and using.

I have this code

```
ls ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt | sort -n | for f in ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt
   do
    read FILE
     Do something with each file and list the results in output file including the name of the string
   done
```

It works, but when I check the list of the strings inside the output file they are like this

```
>chr19:444-555
>chr1:2111-1111
>chr2:345-678
```

why?

Comment: You are better served by not having the `>` character as part of the filename. One slip in handling the name wrong where it is interpreted as a command instead of a filename and `>chr19:444-555` will truncate `chr19:444-555` to `0` or redirect whatever is on stdin to the file `chr19:444-555`

Comment: [You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for your script, for starters! Not sure what the alternative is in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

So... I'm not sure what "Works" here like your question stated.

It seems like you have two problems.

1. Your files are not in sorted order
2. The file names have the leading digits removed

Addressing 1, your command `ls ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt | sort -n | for f in ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt` here doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You are getting a list of files from ls, and then piping that to sort. That probably gives you the output you are looking for, but then you pipe that to `for`, which doesn't make any sense.

In fact you can rewrite your entire script to

```
for f in ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt
   do
    read FILE
     Do something with each file and list the results in output file including the name of the string
   done
```

And you'll have the exact same output. To get this sorted you could do something like:

```
for f in `ls ./"$INPUT"_temp/*_mask3.txt | sort -n`
   do
    read FILE
     Do something with each file and list the results in output file including the name of the string
   done
```

As for the unexpected truncation, that `>` character in your file name is important in your bash shell since it directs the stdout of the preceding command to a specified file. You'll need to insure that when you use variable `$f` from your loop that you stick quotes around that thing to keep `bash` from misinterpreting the file name a `command > file` type of thing.